# Find integer index of rows with NaN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
                    a         b
2011-01-01 00:00:00 1.883381  -0.416629
2011-01-01 01:00:00 0.149948  -1.782170
2011-01-01 02:00:00 -0.407604 0.314168
2011-01-01 03:00:00 1.452354  NaN
2011-01-01 04:00:00 -1.224869 -0.947457
2011-01-01 05:00:00 0.498326  0.070416
2011-01-01 06:00:00 0.401665  NaN
2011-01-01 07:00:00 -0.019766 0.533641
2011-01-01 08:00:00 -1.101303 -1.408561
2011-01-01 09:00:00 1.671795  -0.764629
```

Is there an efficient way to find the "integer" index of rows with NaNs? In this case the desired output should be `[3, 6]`.

Comment: If you just want to select the rows with nan, you can do `df[np.isnan(df['b'])]`

Comment: Following up from @lazy1 - instead of using `numpy`'s `isnan` you can also use `df['b'].isnull()`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For DataFrame `df`:

```
import numpy as np
index = df['b'].index[df['b'].apply(np.isnan)]
```

will give you back the `MultiIndex` that you can use to index back into `df`, e.g.:

```
df['a'].ix[index[0]]
>>> 1.452354
```

For the integer index:

```
df_index = df.index.values.tolist()
[df_index.index(i) for i in index]
>>> [3, 6]
```

Comment: As intuitive as `ix` sounds, for some reasons it sounds like it has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31593712/4288043) in favour of `iloc`

Answer (score 161):

Here is a simpler solution:

`inds = pd.isnull(df).any(1).nonzero()[0]`

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
          0         1
0  0.450319  0.062595
1 -0.673058  0.156073
2 -0.871179 -0.118575
3  0.594188       NaN
4 -1.017903 -0.484744
5  0.860375  0.239265
6 -0.640070       NaN
7 -0.535802  1.632932
8  0.876523 -0.153634
9 -0.686914  0.131185

In [10]: pd.isnull(df).any(1).nonzero()[0]
Out[10]: array([3, 6])
```

Comment: I ended up using this: `np.where(df['b'].notnull())[0]`

Comment: thanks, `.nonzero()[0]` is better than `[i for i, k in enumerate(mask) if k]` .)

Comment: You could probably simplify this further: `r, _ = np.where(df.isna())`

Comment: add `.to_numpy()` to convert in numpy array first - `pd.isnull(df).any(1).to_numpy().nonzero()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nonzero'

Comment: for pandas version 0.25 and on use pd.isnull(df).any(1).to_numpy().nonzero() as [7bStan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6780081/7bstan) mentioned. This will fix [Joe Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3907561/joe-huang)'s problem.

Comment: Very simple pandas solution:

inds = df[df.isnull()].index

You can easily find the null index for a specific column or a list of columns.

Answer (score 28):

One line solution. However it works for one column only.

```
df.loc[pandas.isna(df["b"]), :].index
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I made it into a list by wrapping it in a `list(...)` just like this:`list(df.loc[pandas.isna(df["b"]), :].index)`

Answer (score 12):

And just in case, if you want to find the coordinates of 'nan' for all the columns instead (supposing they are all numericals), here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,3,4,np.nan,2],[3,5,6,np.nan,3,3]])

df
   0  1  2    3    4  5
0  0  1  3  4.0  NaN  2
1  3  5  6  NaN  3.0  3

np.where(np.asanyarray(np.isnan(df)))
(array([0, 1]), array([4, 3]))
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't know if this is too late but you can use np.where to find the indices of non values as such:

```
indices = list(np.where(df['b'].isna()[0]))
```

Answer (score 6):

in the case you have datetime index and you want to have the values:

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df).any(1), :].index.values
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are tests for a few methods:

```py
%timeit np.where(np.isnan(df['b']))[0]
%timeit pd.isnull(df['b']).nonzero()[0]
%timeit np.where(df['b'].isna())[0]
%timeit df.loc[pd.isna(df['b']), :].index
```

And their corresponding timings:

```
333 µs ± 9.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
280 µs ± 220 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
313 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
6.84 ms ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

It would appear that `pd.isnull(df['DRGWeight']).nonzero()[0]` wins the day in terms of timing, but that any of the top three methods have comparable performance.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution is `list(np.where(df['b'].isnull())[0])`

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the index values for nan in every column:

```
df.loc[pd.isna(df).any(1), :].index
```

Comment: This creates a new data frame with all rows containing Nan values, the returns its index

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simpler take:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,3,4,np.nan,2],[3,5,6,np.nan,3,3]])

inds = np.asarray(df.isnull()).nonzero()

(array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([4, 3], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for all indexes of rows with NaN values.
My working solution:

```
def get_nan_indexes(data_frame):
    indexes = []
    print(data_frame)
    for column in data_frame:
        index = data_frame[column].index[data_frame[column].apply(np.isnan)]
        if len(index):
            indexes.append(index[0])
    df_index = data_frame.index.values.tolist()
    return [df_index.index(i) for i in set(indexes)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the dataframe be named ***df*** and the column of interest(i.e. **the column in which we are trying to find nulls**) is ***'b'***. Then the following snippet gives the desired index of null in the dataframe:

```
   for i in range(df.shape[0]):
       if df['b'].isnull().iloc[i]:
           print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    index_nan = []
        for index, bool_v in df["b"].iteritems().isna():
           if bool_v == True:
               index_nan.append(index)
    print(index_nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and fast solution to the question is:

```
# Find the integer index of nulls
nan_idx = np.where(df['column_name'].isnull())[0]

# Find actual index of the nan's
nan_idx = df.iloc[nan_idx].index
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

```
# Find the index of nulls

indx = df[df.isnull()].index

# Find the index of nulls of a column or a group of columns

indx_A = df[df['A'].isnull()].index 

col_list = ['A','B','C']

indx_col_list = df[df[col_list].isnull()].index
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DataFrame` object has a built in function `isna()` these days, which means you could also solve it as follows:

In case one NaN value is sufficient to return the index:

```
index_na = df.index[df.isna().any(1)]
```

In case all of them have to be NaN:

```
index_na = df.index[df.isna().all(1)]
```

To return the numeric index for the first case:

```
index_na_num = np.where(df.isna().any(1)[0])
```