# Python Pandas find all rows where all values are NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

So I have a dataframe with 5 columns. I would like to pull the indices where all of the columns are NaN. I was using this code:

```
nan = pd.isnull(df.all)
```

but that is just returning false because it is logically saying no not all values in the dataframe are null. There are thousands of entries so I would prefer to not have to loop through and check each entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It should just be:

```
df.isnull().all(1)
```

The `index` can be accessed like:

```
df.index[df.isnull().all(1)]
```

#### Demonstration

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1, np.nan), (10, 2)))
df
```

[image]

```
idx = df.index[df.isnull().all(1)]
nans = df.ix[idx]
nans
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**code**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((1, np.nan), (10000, 5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Why `all(1)`? I see that's the correct answer to this problem but I can't wrap my head around it. We have a table of Trues and Falses, and we want all the *rows* where there are only (all) True values. So why look at the column axis (1) rather than the index (0)?

Comment: @Jinx the `all(1)` is interesting isn't it?  If you try just plain old `all()`, or more explicitly `all(axis=0)`, you'll find that Pandas calculates the value *per column*.  By specifying `all(1)`, or more explicitly `all(axis=1)`, you're checking if all values are null *per row*.  For more detail, see the documentation for [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your dataframe is named `df`, you can use boolean indexing to check if all columns (`axis=1`) are null.  Then take the index of the result.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3))
df.iloc[-2:, :] = np.nan
>>> df
          0         1         2
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3       NaN       NaN       NaN
4       NaN       NaN       NaN

nan = df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)].index

>>> nan
Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the master himself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033137/6664393

```
nans = pd.isnull(df).all(1).nonzero()[0]
```