# Why there is no rows which are all null values in my dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have found some values which seems all columns are null.
The examples are below
[image]

I want to remove there rows. But when I use the method from the link below,
the return dataframe has no rows which should represent the all value null rows.
[Python Pandas find all rows where all values are NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884538/python-pandas-find-all-rows-where-all-values-are-nan)

So I want to know what's wrong with my data frame. Is the NA matters ?
What should I do to get the null rows' row number?

Besides, I use

```
df_features.loc[df_features['sexo'].isnull() & (df_features['age']=='NA'),:]
```

But it returns no rows from my data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df_features[df_features['sexo'].notnull()]
```

It seems you need:

```
df_features[(df_features['sexo'].notnull()) & (df_features['age'] != 'NA')]
```

Sample:

```
df_features = pd.DataFrame({'sexo':[np.nan,2,3],
                   'age':['10','20','NA']})

print (df_features)
  age  sexo
0  10   NaN
1  20   2.0
2  NA   3.0

a = df_features[(df_features['sexo'].notnull()) & (df_features['age'] != 'NA')]
print (a)
  age  sexo
1  20   2.0
```

---

But it seems your colunmns with `NA` values are not numeric, but string.

If need convert some columns to numeric, try [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), parameter `errors='coerce'` means convert all values which cannot bye parsed to numeric to `NaN`:

```
df_features = pd.DataFrame({'sexo':[np.nan,2,3],
                   'age':['10','20','NA']})

print (df_features)
  age  sexo
0  10   NaN
1  20   2.0
2  NA   3.0

df_features['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df_features['age'], errors='coerce')
print (df_features)
    age  sexo
0  10.0   NaN
1  20.0   2.0
2   NaN   3.0

a = df_features[(df_features['sexo'].notnull()) & (df_features['age'].notnull())]
print (a)
    age  sexo
1  20.0   2.0
```

Comment: Yeah, I find the NA are string and in data they are '  NA' and ' NA'.