# Select the row which are NaN dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    0           1       
2   Ticket      Open Time   
3   5302684589  2020.06.17 01:32:13
...
4   5302717457  2020.06.17 03:11:57
5   NaN         0
6   Closed P/L: Closed P/L:
7   Ticket      Open Time
8   5302718245  2020.06.17 03:12:14
...
```

I have a database which I have loaded as dataframe by using pandas, I only need the first part data, namely for this example the rows from no.2  to no.4: we can use df.iloc[2:4] which is easy; \n

However, I have many dataframe that the first part data is not from #2 to #4. \n

Lucikly, for all dataframe there is one line which is NaN in the first column, for this example, no.5 is NaN in the begining, so I want to identify which row is NaN and then I can know the index of the NaN rows that I can quickly select the first part data I want. \n

my question is how can I select the data I want by using the NaN row, others may also have this problem, so I post it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas find all rows where all values are NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884538/python-pandas-find-all-rows-where-all-values-are-nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the first index of the row where all entries are `nan`

`df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)].index[0]`

You can now do the `df.loc[0:df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)].index[0],:]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dataframe of non-nan rows, you can do a `df.dropna()`. Here is the official pandas documentation in case you want to drop inplace or column wise.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 0):

df[df.iloc[:,0].isnull()].index[0] can solve this problem, based on XXavier's answer, all credit comes to him, many thanks